# sorting in quick sort algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This is my program to sort list or array in quick sort algorithm the pivot in the midst of array how can chose the pivot randomly?and what is the algorithm can i use it to sort the array by  quick sort (randomly).

```
 public static int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 7};
 public static void main(String[] args) {


     qs(a, 0, 6);
     for(int p=0;p<a.length;p++)
     System.out.println("after sort" + a[p]);

 }

 public static void qs(int a[], int f, int l) {
     int i = f;
     int j = l;

     int x = (l + f )/ 2;
     while (i < j) {
         while (a[i] < a[x])
             i = i + 1;
         while (a[j] > a[x])
             j = j - 1;

         if (i < j) {
             int s = a[i];
             a[i] = a[j];
             a[j] = s;
             i = i + 1;
             j = j - 1;
         }
     }

     if (f < j)
         qs(a, f, j);

     if (i < l)
         qs(a, i, l);
 }

 public void disply(int a[])
 {
     for(int p=0;p<a.length;p++)
         System.out.println("after sort" + a[p]);
 }
```

Comment: I removed the `C++` tag as this is obviously about Java

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Is the implementation not working or what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean with `how can chose the pivot randomly`? AFAIK quicksort has a defined pivot position in each (sub)array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = (int)(Math.random()*(f-l-1)) + l;
```

---

`Math.random` gives a random double from 0.0 to 1.0. Multiplying this by the length of the interval and then adding the start of the interval gives a random number in the interval.

Comment: 1)I forgot a `- 1` in the code
2)As suggested, you should correct your algorithm

Answer (score 1):

First thing I could observe is that your algorithm is not always correct, check this test case:

```
{ 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 1, 7 }
```

Your output is:

```
after sort1
after sort2
after sort3
after sort5
after sort3
after sort5
after sort7
```

I think that you should update `i` and `j` even if they are equal, because you don't want to have partitions overlapping, and then you can change your second recursive call to something more logical:

```
if (i < l)
  qs(a, i, l);
```

For random you can use solution proposed by @jeremy-bentham, and you can also check java.util.Random class.